# Validate string before saving it to Mysql for chars taking more than 3 bytes

Tags: mysql, database, character-encoding, char

The Mysql db I am using has char encoding utf8 but certain sets of chars which take beyond 3 bytes are not getting saved. I could have changed the encoding to utf8mb4 but that is not an option. All I want to do is validate a string to check if the string will get saved in Mysql. I don't want to unnecessarily limit my chars to ASCII. How do I check if a char will take more than three bytes?

Comment: so you want it checked in mysql or in programming language

Comment: I want to check it in programming language so that i dont try to save the string in mysql and endup getting an exception.

Comment: then why dont you mention the programming environment in your question.

Comment: Oh sorry for that! I am using JAVA.

Comment: String s = new String("stringvalue");

byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("UTF-8");

System.out.println("bytes.length = "+bytes.length);

Comment: Are you checking a single character?  Or checking for a long string that might or might not contain a 4-byte UTF-8 character amongst shorter characters?

Comment: I am checking a string of size roughly 50-100 and even if a single char does not fit into utf8, I should not try to save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plan A:

In your app language, convert your string to hex.  Then look for `f0`.  That byte would indicate utf8mb4 is needed.

In MySQL, the expression is `HEX(col) REGEXP '^(..)*f0'`.

Plan B:

Attempt to insert your text into a `CHARACTER SET utf8` column of a spare table.  Read it back and see if it matches.  Storing a 4-byte character will either turn it into question marks or truncate the string.  Either way, it won't match.

Comment: @mAvericK - Oops, I forget to include `HEX()` in the MySQL code.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to insert the data in mysql query only rather than programmaticaly, then you can use the length() function to check for the byte length.

MySQL provides the LENGTH function to get a length of a string in bytes, and the CHAR_LENGTH function to get the length of a string in characters. If a string contains the multi-bytes character, the result of the LENGTH function is greater than the result of the CHAR_LENGTH() function

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-character-set/

Sample query follows

```
insert into x_table(data_string)
SELECT 'šč' as data_string where length('šč')<4
```

in Java check length before inserting into mysql

using

```
String s = new String("stringvalue");

byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("UTF-8");

System.out.println("bytes.length = "+bytes.length);
```

bytes.length can be checked before inserting (String.getBytes().length).

Comment: But that does not say if a single character in a long string is a 4-byte UTF-8 code.